# scope.$watch in directive link function not getting called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this factory,

```
.factory('authentication', [function() {

    return {
      loginRequired: false
    };
  }]);
```

I have this controller,

```
.controller('TopNavCtrl', ['$scope', 'authentication', function($scope, authentication) {

  $scope.login = function() {
    authentication.loginRequired = true;
  };

}]);
```

and I have this link function in a directive,

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    scope.show = false;

    scope.$watch(authentication.loginRequired, function(value) {
      scope.show = value;
    });
  }
```

When `authentication.loginRequired = true;` is done in the controller, the `scope.$watch` in the directive isn't called.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Scope.$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) accepts as first parameter expression or function. What you are passing as first parameter is a **value** stored in `authetication.loginRequired`.

Following will work (assuming you have correctly injected `authetication` factory):

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    scope.show = false;

    scope.$watch(function(){return authentication.loginRequired;}, function(value) {
      scope.show = value;
    });
  }
```

Comment: FWIW, you can also assign the factory to the scope and then use `$watch` with a string expression.

Comment: Please do share what you mean, Michael. It's always good to see alternatives.

Answer (score 10):

Following up @jusio's answer, it's also possible to use a string expression as long as you make your factory part of the scope:

```
scope.authentication = authentication;
scope.$watch('authentication.loginRequired', function(value) {
...
});
```

That's so because when a `$watch` is provided with a string expression, it evaluates that string against its scope.

You should decide whether it's worth cluttering your directive's scope so you can have an arguably more readable code. If you're already doing it for another reason, then it's no big deal.